# Dynamic number of columns in flatlist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

In react native , I need to create a list with a number of items, but the texts are of different lengths. So, I can't determine how many items can be included in a single row. I need to calculate how many items can be included in a row and display it. As shown below on the 7th line, it can only include 2 items, so I need to display the 3rd item in the next row. How can I do that?

[image: 7 th line]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the list using map function:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
  {Data?.map((i, j) => <YourComponent key={j} />)}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **FlatList** you can use the prop `contentContainerStyle` to achieve it by adding a `flexDirection` to "row" and a `flexWrap` to "wrap".

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection : "row", flexWrap : "wrap"}}
  data={...}
  renderItem{...}
/>
```